# JavaScript (Beginner-Level) Kata - Building a Calculator Using Functions

Tags: javascript

I'm solving the following kata:  **Write a program that takes as its first argument one of the words ‘sum,’ ‘product,’ ‘mean,’ or ‘sqrt’  and for further arguments a series of numbers. The program applies the appropriate function to  the series.**

I have solved it (code below) but it is bulky and inefficient. I'm looking to re-write it have a single function **calculator** that calls the other functions (i.e. function **sum**, function **product**).

My question: how do I write the functions sum, product, sqrt, etc so when called by the function calculator, they properly take the arguments of calculator and compute the math.

Below is the bulky code:

```
function calculator() {

    var sumTotal = 0;
    var productTotal = 1;
    var meanTotal = 0;
    var sqrt;

    if(arguments[0] === "sum") {
        for(i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            sumTotal += arguments[i];
        }
    return sumTotal;
    }

    if(arguments[0] === "product") {
        for(i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            productTotal *= arguments[i];
        }
    return productTotal;
    }

    if(arguments[0] === "mean") {
        for(i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            meanTotal += arguments[i];
        }
    return meanTotal / (arguments.length-1);
    }

    if(arguments[0] === "sqrt") {
            sqrt = Math.sqrt(arguments[1]);
        }
    return sqrt;

}


calculator("sqrt", 17);
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it as such.

Comment: No it isn't. I'm new to programming and JS. I started w/ Codecademy, but am trying to find ways to improve. I found the link to various Katas and am simply going through them to try to improve: http://www.knowing.net/index.php/2006/06/16/15-exercises-to-know-a-programming-language-part-1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just create an object with the functions you need, and then have the calculator function call the correct one.

```
var operations = {
  sum: function() { /* sum function */ },
  product: function() { /* product function */ },
  mean: function() { /* mean function */ },
  sqrt: function() { /* sqrt function */ }
};

function calculator(operation) {
  operation = operations[operation];
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return operation.apply(this, args);
}
```

[You can see an example of this in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZxBV/).

If you don't quite understand what I'm doing in my code, I reccomend reading about [`call` and `apply` in Javascript](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) and also about [objects in Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter. I've got the call-and-apply link open and am going through the article now.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your entire arguments list to another function using the [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method:

```
if(arguments[0] === "sum") {
   return sum.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

With your operations in separate methods:

```
function sum() {
  var sumTotal = 0;
  for(i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            sumTotal += arguments[i];
  }
  return sumTotal;
}
```

Comment: `arguments.slice(1, arguments.length)` doesn't work because `arguments` is not actually an array and does not have the `slice` method in its prototype.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll make a change but your answer is much better than mine anyway.