# How can I convert a string into a math operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I've got a string that is a mathematic equation and I want to split it and then calculate it. I know I can use the eval() function to do this, but I'm interested if there's an alternative way to do this - specifically by splitting the strings first. So I've got something like

```
var myString = "225 + 15 - 10"
var newString = myString.split(" ");
```

This would turn myString into an array:

```
["225", "+", "15", "-", "10"];
```

My next task is to turn all the odd-numbered strings into integers, which I think I could use parseInt(); for. My question is, how do I turn the "+" and "-" into actual arithmetic operators? So that at the end I am left with a mathematic expression which I can calculate?

Is this possible?

Comment: The ugly way would be multiple if statements.

Comment: Make a real parser, otherwise this exercise is pretty pointless :) Here's a good article http://parsingintro.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Unless you have an exceptional reason, just `eval` it.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729963/javascript-beginner-level-kata-building-a-calculator-using-functions

Comment: This may help as well, you are really just looking to build a math parser.  This is a common academic exercise in Computer Science curriculums.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser

Answer (score 105):

```
var math_it_up = {
    '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
    '-': function (x, y) { return x - y }
}​​​​​​​;

math_it_up['+'](1, 2) == 3;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. This would work - but what if the entire string is input by a user? So I don't have the control over what the numbers inside the string are. In other words if this is a calculator and the user punches in "225 + 15 - 10", I split the string up, and take whatever the numbers and operators are and turn them in to a math expression. In the solution you offered - how would I automatically replace x and y -- not define them manually?

Comment: Normally I'd go the parser direction (mentioned above by @Esailija) but the context provided in the question makes this a good, simple solution. Edit: for complete control over user input, write a parser.

Comment: If `+` and `-` are alternating with numbers you can simply loop through it.

Comment: @user1775598, There are several ways that you could do it. One way would be to simply loop over the string and check hasOwnProperty on your math_it_up object for each element; if it's true, call it with the preceding and succeeding indices in the array as the arguments to the function. Of course, you might still want to verify that those indices exist and are valid numbers... and you'll also want to respect precedence rules if you extend this to `/` and `*`... The more sophisticated and the more robust you make this, the closer it's going to come to a parser.

Answer (score 103):

JavaScript's `eval` function was mentioned in a comment by Oliver Morgan and I just wanted to flush out how you could use `eval` as a solution to your problem.

The `eval` function takes a string and then returns the value of that string considered as a math operation. For example,

```
eval("3 + 4")
```

will return 7 as 3 + 4 = 7.

This helps in your case because you have an array of strings that you want you want to treat as the mathematical operators and operands that they represent.

```
myArray = ["225", "+", "15", "-", "10"];
```

Without converting any of the strings in your array into integers or operators you could write

```
eval(myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2]);
```

which will translate to

```
eval("225" + "+" + "15");
```

which will translate to

```
eval("225 + 15");
```

which will return 240, the value of adding 225 to 15.

Or even more generic:

```
eval(myArray.join(' '));
```

which will translate to

```
eval("225 + 15 - 10");
```

which will return 230, the value of adding 15 to 225 and substract 10. So you can see that in your case it may be possible to skip converting the strings in your array into integers and operators and, as Oliver Morgan said, just `eval` it.

Comment: I'm thinking of using some "mathy" expression in form validation and a parser is just overkill. Using `eval()` allows me to simply parse some strings such as `<|oh` for validation (where `oh` references another form input class/id/etc).

Comment: But don't use eval() too much. There are a number of reasons why:
https://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval

Comment: Never use eval. For anything. It is a huge security hole in JS.

Comment: Although powerful, do not use eval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: this could be dangerous if input coming from user

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `isNaN(Number(array[x]))` and a `switch` for anything that doesn't satisfy the condition.