# Calculate equation like excel jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have an HTML like ,

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-column="A" value="5" data-row="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-column="B" value="2" data-row="1" /></td>

  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" data-column="A" data-row="2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="9" data-column="B" data-row="2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <th><input type="text" data-column="A" data-row="3"  data-equation="A1+A2-B1" />      </th>
     <th><input type="text" data-column="B" data-row="3"  data-equation="B1+B2"  /></th>
   </tr>

 </table>
```

And my javascript like

```
 $('input').each(function(){
 if($(this).attr('data-equation')!=undefined){
    var equation=$(this).attr('data-equation');
    $(this).val(calculate(equation))
 }
});

function calculate(equation){
  result=0;
  //calculate value and return,i dont know how to calculate
  return result;
}
```

I need to calculate the value based on **data-equation**,In the equation ,First element refer **data-column** and second refer **data-row**

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/6K7z9/9/)

Comment: You will need to split the expression on none alphanumeric characters and start from there.

Comment: A nice question but it wont be something as simple as executing a simple equation, you ll have to write a parser to first separate all the operators and operands

Comment: Do you mean the second refers to the data-row?

Comment: @Nimnam1 Yes.........

Answer (score 5):

If someone is still looking for similar solution, I'd suggest http://mathjs.org/.

Simple spreadsheet-like example:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var calculate = function(n) {
    var expr = n.attr('data-equation')
      , ret  = expr;
    
    if (expr) {
      try {
        ret = math.eval(expr);
      } catch(e) {
        ret = 'Syntax error in equation!';  
      }
    }

    var obj = {};
    obj[n.attr('id')] = ret;
    math.import(obj, { override: true });

    return ret;
  };

  $.fn.equations = function() {

    $(this).each(function() {
      var n = $(this);

      n.focus(function() {
        n.val(n.attr('data-equation'));
      });

      n.blur(function() {
        n.attr('data-equation', n.val());
        n.attr('title', n.val());
        n.val(calculate(n));
      });

      if (!n.attr('data-equation')) {
        n.blur();
      }

      n.val(calculate(n));
    });

  };

  $('input').equations();

});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Equations</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.5.1/math.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>A1: <input type="text" id="A1" value="2+2"/></p>
    <p>A2: <input type="text" id="A2" value="16"/></p>
    <p>A3: <input type="text" id="A3" value="A1+A2"/></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

With substrings:

```
var math_it_up = {
    '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
    '-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
    '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
    '/': function (x, y) { return x / y }
};

$('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-equation')!=undefined){
        var equation=$(this).attr('data-equation');
        $(this).val(calculate(equation));
    }
});

function calculate(equation){
    result=0;
    index=2;

    var value1 = $('input[data-column="'+equation.substring(0,1)+'"]
[data-row="'+equation.substring(1,2)+'"]').val();

    result = parseInt(value1);

    while(equation.substring(index,index+1) !== "") {
        var operator = equation.substring(index, index+1);

        var value = $('input[data-column="'+equation.substring(index + 1, index+2)+'"]
[data-row="'+equation.substring(index + 2, index+3)+'"]').val();

        result = math_it_up[operator](result, parseInt(value));

        index += 3;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I used `math_it_up` function from [How can I convert a string into a math operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077923/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-a-math-operator-in-javascript)

You can enlarge operators by adding yours(e.g modulo). Note that I didn't check if `value1` or `value` is a valid number.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6K7z9/12/)**

Comment: math_it_up is definitely the write way to map the operations. don't know why I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate method to using the eval function.  To implement this fully with all the mathematical operations is probably more work than it's worth so be advised there but here's a simplistic implementation.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6K7z9/13/)

```
function calculate(equation){
    var vals = getValues(equation),
        operators = getOperators(equation),
        num1 = vals[0];
    for(var i=0; i<operators.length; i++){
        // simplistic you'll need to be more careful of order of operations
        // if you're going to be using things other than addition and subtraction
        num1 = calculateOperation(operators[i], num1, vals[i+1]);
    }
    return num1;
}

function calculateOperation(op, num1, num2){
    // add more ops as necessary
    if (op === '+'){
        return num1 + num2;
    } else if (op === '-'){
        return num1 - num2;
    }
}

function getValues(eq){
    // use regex because there might be more than one character denoting a row or column
    var column, row,
        operatorRegex = /[\+|\-]/;
        return eq.split(operatorRegex).map(function(identifier){
            column = identifier.replace(/[0-9]+/, "");
            row = identifier.replace(/[A-Za-z]+/, "");
            return parseInt($('[data-column="'+column+'"][data-row="'+row+'"]').val(), 10);
        });
}

function getOperators(eq){
     var ops = eq.split(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/);
     // remove the quotes and return
     return ops.slice(1, ops.length-1);
}

$('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-equation')!=undefined){
        var equation=$(this).attr('data-equation');
        $(this).val(calculate(equation))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely using this plugin https://github.com/xsanisty/jquery-calx

I create this while ago, and still maintaining it, but instead of `data-column` and `data-equation`, mine using `data-cell` and `data-formula`

```
<form id="sheet">
    <input type="text" data-cell="A1" />
    <input type="text" data-cell="A2" />
    <input type="text" data-cell="A3" data-formula="A1*A2" />
</form>
```

and just need to initiate the plugin

```
<script>
    $('#sheet').calx()
</script>
```

and now, it should calculate all the formula defined inside the `#sheet`, you can even use a lot of excel compatible formula in it

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with `eval()` function:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        var col = $(this).data("column");
        var row = $(this).data("row");
        var val = $(this).val();
        var equation = $(this).data("equation");

        if(equation == undefined)
        {
            eval(col+row+"="+val);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).val(eval(equation));
        }
    });
});
```