# Storing comparison/boolean operators in a variable in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, comparison-operators

Is there any way to store operators as variables in extjs? I need this for filtering. I'm aware of the `operators` config in `filter`, but for reasons too complicated I have to use `filterFn` instead.

So, suppose I have this filter object:

```
filterObj.property = 'price';
filterObj.value = input;
filterObj.operator = opVar;

filters.push(filterObj);
store.addFilter(filters);
```

Here, I can pass a string like '<', '>' etc as `opVar` and it would turn into a comparison operator. This works perfectly.

What I need is the equivalent of this in `filterFn`. How do I use `opVar` there.

As a last resort, I think I'll have to use `switch`. Any other ideas?

Comment: As you suggested, a `filterFn` is there because the logic is too complicated for a simple comparison. You'll need to implement the check yourself. Alternatively, you could transform the values before filtering them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using, using the answer jrajav gave [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077923/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-a-math-operator-in-javascript/13077966#comment37936492_13077966)

```
var operate = {
    '>': function(a,b) {return a>b ;},
    '>=': function(a,b) {return a>=b ;},
    '<': function(a,b) {return a<b ;},
    '<=': function(a,b) {return a<=b ;},
    '==': function(a,b) {return a==b ;},
    '=': function(a,b) {return a==b ;},
    '!=': function(a,b) {return a!=b ;},
    '<>': function(a,b) {return a!=b ;}
};
```

And then you can do:

```
var greater = '>';
var a= 10;
var b = someValue;
operate[greater](a,b);
```