# Turning a string, '+' into the + operator

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Hi i'm making a String Calculator and all it currently does is add. I'm using coffeescript and in the code provided finalnum is 0, operator is '+' and it's iterating through an array of integers. I plan on adding more operators later and am looking for a simpler way (not a massive if else) to quickly change a string to it's corresponding operator. Thanks for your help!

```
for num in equation_array
    finalnum = finalnum operator num
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077923/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-a-math-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to abstract using functions instead of trying to abstract over the operator directly.

```
var ops = {
  '+': function(a,b){ return a + b; },
  '-': function(a,b){ return a - b; },
  '*': function(a,b){ return a * b; },
  '/': function(a,b){ return a / b; }
};

var opstr = "+";
final_num = ops[opstr](final_num, num);
```