# How to write a formula in javascript based on input ids and calculate it?

Tags: javascript, formula, selector

I have a simple form in javascript. I'm going to calculate a formula.

I want to select elements by id and then detects operators and finally calculate final result.

```
<p>
  V1: <input id="v1" />
</p>
<p>
  V2: <input id="v2" />
</p>
<p>
  V3: <input id="v3" />
</p>
<p>
  V4: <input id="v4" />
</p>
<p>
  Fromula: <input id="f1" />
</p>
<p>
  <button id="doAction">
    Calculate
  </button>
</p>
```

Example expression is: (v1+v2)*v3-(v4-v1)/v2

Comment: in future, post CODE, not images of code ... as for "what codes or library is required" ... the answer is ... *your code*, or *some* library that *your code* can use - this is not a code writing service, and requests for library recommendations are off topic

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Edit your question, add your code.

Comment: Try and find information on `document.getElementById()` and experiment with it. Also make sure to convert the `.values` of the input fields into numeric values before adding them to other values using the `+` operator.

Comment: What have you tried?  SO isn't a code-writing service, and [you are expected to do a lot of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and attempt to solve the problem yourself.  If you don't know where to start, a quick search for "*javascript add input values*" shows some answers with code to get you started, have you tried that?  Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540751/how-get-total-sum-from-input-box-values-using-javascript

Comment: What `^` is in your context?

Comment: 2^3=8.      2^1=2     2^2=4     3^2=9

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and automatic mapping by ids (no need to call `getElementById`) to have that implementation

```js
doAction.addEventListener("click", () => {

  const formula = f1.value
    .replaceAll("v1", v1.value || 0)
    .replaceAll("v2", v2.value || 0)
    .replaceAll("v3", v3.value || 0)
    .replaceAll("v4", v4.value || 0)
  result.innerHTML = eval(formula)
})
```

```html
<p>
  V1: <input id="v1" />
</p>
<p>
  V2: <input id="v2" />
</p>
<p>
  V3: <input id="v3" />
</p>
<p>
  V4: <input id="v4" />
</p>
<p>
  Formula: <input id="f1" />
</p>
<p id="result">

</p>
<p>
  <button id="doAction">
    Calculate
  </button>
</p>
```

But one thing you need to be aware of, `eval` is not safe 100%, if you don't protect your code properly, somebody may inject malicious scripts. Here is the sample case

```js
eval("alert('Not safe')")
```

If you want to have a safer way, you need to have a function to convert strings to operators with numbers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372694/9201587)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this solution:

```
var doAction = document.getElementById('doAction');

doAction.addEventListener('click', (s, e) => {  
  var scope=expressionArray("(v1+v2)*v3-v4");
  var formula = document.getElementById('f1').value;
  const result = math.evaluate(formula, scope)
  console.log(result);
});
function expressionArray(init)
{
    var text="";
  var split_var = init.split(/[*-/+()]+/);
  var obj={};
  split_var.forEach((s,e)=>{    
    if(document.getElementById(s))
    {
        obj[s]=document.getElementById(s).value;
    }    
  });
  return obj;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bshafiei/zyv7bsfd/51/